# .npmignore extending / inheriting from .gitignore

Tags: git, npm, gitignore, package.json, npmignore

I know I can't use them both at once, but is there a way to make `.npmignore` file extending `.gitignore`? I have dozens of rules in `.gitignore` and I want to use them all + one additional for npm package. How can I do it without duplicating all the rules?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's any mechanism to do this, but it should be pretty simple to script! Here's how I would tackle this:

Set up a [`prepack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) npm script in your `package.json`that:

1. Copies your `.gitignore` file to a `.npmignore`
2. Adds your extended rules to the `.npmignore` file after the copy finishes. I would suggest defining these extra rules in a file somewhere, we'll call it `extra_rules_file` for clarity in the below example.

Then, optionally a `postpack` script that deletes your `.npmignore` now that you don't need it (and maybe don't want to commit it, since it's a generated file)

---

For example:

#### package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepack": "cp .gitignore .npmignore && cat extra_rules_file >> .npmignore",
    "postpack": "rm .npmignore"
  }
}
```

#### extra_rules_file

```
whatever/rules/you/want/**/*
```

Comment: Yeah, that'd be some solution and I gave it a point. But at the same time, the drawback in limiting developers' environment to Unix is too big for such a small thing.

Comment: Yeah, this answer would limit you to Unix, or something like git bash on windows. However, you could instead just reference node.js scripts here that use the standard library to do these same `cp`, `cat`, and `rm` equivalents in a platform-independent way.

Answer (score 0):

[common-ignore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/common-ignore) (npm package) looks promising.